# Java-like annotations in C++

Tags: java, c++, annotations

Is there something like Java's annotations in C++ ?

For example, the @Override annotation marks a function that it overrides another function, and if it wouldn't, it would give an error at compile time.

I am looking for something like this in C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Explicit_overrides_and_final) will have this feature, where you can explicitly specify whether a member function is meant to override a base class' function, use a default implementation generated by the compiler and much more.

Comment: Now that C++11 has been released, is there any documentation that describes this feature?

Comment: Also, which feature are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: Just click on the C++0x link above, it takes you exactly to that section in the wikipedia docs.

Answer (score 22):

C++11 provides support for *generalized attributes*, which can be seen as superset of Java annotations, as they can be applied not just to variables/functions, but also to statements, for example. But C++11 defines only syntax for generalized attributes, not means for user to define them.

This article gives good overview of *generalized attributes*: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/18/cxx11-generalized-attributes/

GCC supports this feature from version 4.8, according to: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

To implement support for user-defined attributes, compiler plugins are promising, especially based on high-level language integration, like https://fedorahosted.org/gcc-python-plugin/

Comment: that's the closest thing to an annotation I've seen so far! Thanks for this helpful answer

Comment: The fedorahosted link is dead

Answer (score 1):

There is  C++0x, which has the override 'annotation'. Or, if you wanted to achieve more of the Java "interface" like-code that errors if you don't implement methods, you could use an abstract class:

```
    class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Extended : public Base {
public:

    void foo2() {
        cout << "hi" << endl;
};

int main() {
    Extended e;
    e.foo();
}
```

This will result in a compiler error if you don't override foo in the base class. The issue, however, is that the base class can't have it's own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the language for this.  The best you could hope for is a compiler-specific option.  I'd start by checking the documentation for "pragma" for your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what JAVA provides in general, but for the specific functionality you mentioned, C++ has the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    void foo() override { ... }
};
```

You'll get a helpful compiler error message if `Base` doesn't have a corresponding `virtual void foo()`.

Another functionally-similar keyword is [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final), which can be used to say that the function is an override that can't be further overridden in further-derived classes.  (The same keyword can be used to say a class can't be derived from).

Comment: If you are not sure, it's best not to mention anything.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev the question is ambiguous in that OP may have wanted functionality akin to what I've mentioned, or been curious about a more general annotation feature.  I'm not sure what he wanted, but nobody else could be based on the question either, and I've documented C++ features related to one possible intent behind the question.  If you've got nothing useful to contribute, it's best not to mention anything.