# What would be the best equivalent of Java annotations in C++?

Tags: java, c++, annotations

I'm a Java programmer and I'm learning c++ 11 which I like a lot. I really think it's great but I'm missing the notion of annotation in this language.

First, is there something close to Java style annotation in the standard ? I think there's not after my research.

What would be the closer, standard way (no compiler extensions), to "simulate" a Java style annotation in c++ ?

And please don't mention the c++ 11 `override` annotation. I mean user defined annotations.

Comment: What would you like to do with these user-defined annotations?

Comment: According to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4689981/1979005), noooopeee. Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4689756/1979005

Comment: What I have in mind is porting one of those fancy ORM such as Hibernate to c++ :) I know there are already lots of existing solutions out there, but I really like the annotation style.

Comment: The idea in C++ **may** be that anything you would do with tooling processing annotations at runtime / as a build step you should be doing with templates instead.

Comment: Interesting comment. What would be the mind process to "translate" a java annotation to a c++ template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like annotations in standard C++. For alternatives, it depends on why you want to use annotations.

- one of the use of annotations in Java is to mark some methods or classes with meta-data so it can be retrieved through reflection at runtime. But reflection in standard C++ is very limited, so there is nothing like that. I haven't had a look at boost::reflect, maybe it can be useful to you.
- another use of annotations is to have tools that intervenes at compile time to inject some code or to do checks. The tool to do this kind of stuff in C++ is the preprocessor.

Comment: I was more thinking of runtime stuff. But you're right there are 2 different retention types in Java annotations.