# java annotation vs c++ pragma

Tags: java, c++

Can I think of c++ prgamas similar to java annotations? I understand that pragma is compiler specific but I am wondering if their overall purpose is similar to java annotations.

Comment: Not really.  With Java annotations you're free to define your own annotations, and your own annotation processors to perform code generation, etc.

Comment: Annotations are used meta information that can be applied to methods, fields and/or classes and can be used at runtime. Pragmas are used to give the compiler instructions about the piece of code it will compile and will only be used at compile time (they can cause the compiler to generate comments/hints for the linker though, but they are not directly used by the linker afaik).

Comment: @lucian.pantelimon It depends on the pragma.  A pragma could cause the compiler to generate code which is executed at runtime, and VC++ definitely has pragmas which affect linking.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I totally agree with you, they are used to manipulate the way the object code (library, executable) is generated. I don't remember being possible to query the pragma directives from the code without using another directive (macros included) and, afaik, its "value" cannot be changed by code - only by the use of another directive. Thus, `pragma` is only used at compile time. +1 for improving the explanation. Also, feel free to use my comment if you want to provide an answer that Abraham can accept, otherwise I will do it tomorrow -kinda busy atm.

Comment: Java annotations correspond very closely to the concept of attributes in C# and VB.

Comment: @lucian.pantelimon `pragma` doesn't (at least in the implementations I know) propagate as such beyond the compiler, but what the compiler does definitely can have an impact at runtime, so a pragma can, indirectly, impact runtime.  A pragma could, for example, generate specially named flags which could be interrogated at runtime.  (I think that's what you're saying, but it really should be made clear.)

Comment: Thanks all for your explanation, should any of you provide some of the comments as an Answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In http://codesynthesis.com/products/odb/ there's a sample of C++ pragmas similar to Java annotations. In fact, they are similar to Hibernate annotations:

```
#pragma db object
class person
{
    ...
    private:
        friend class odb::access;
        person () {}

        #pragma db id
        string email_;

        string name_;
        unsigned short age_;
};
```

There is more information in [Java-like annotations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689756/java-like-annotations-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Pragma directives are not analogous to annotations as they are what their name specifies, compiler directives. And as what the previous responses indicate, can and usually are processed precompilation stage.

But since in Java compilation is different than in C++, herein lies the reason for the difference.